# Evaluating a sum with binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k^r} a^k b^{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have come across the following sum evoking the binomial theorem:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k^r} a^k b^{n-k},$$
where $r > 0$ is a positive *real* constant and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary real numbers.
Could anyone suggest an effective method how to approach this sum in order to obtain a closed-form solution or at least an asymptotic estimate? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean from $k=1$ to $k=n$, right?

Comment: @PaulRS Yes, of course, sorry for the mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: The formula is exactly eq (5) in: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/31-3/hsu.pdf   Incidentally I think some points might be missed here and there: the binomial(n,k)  is a transform that has a closed form for either EGF or OGF  input sequences; if the generating function is know for either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be partially evaluated using convolutions. Let $c_k:=\frac{a^k}{k^r}$ and $d_k:=\binom{n}{k}b^k$, with the convention that $d_k=0$ for $k>n$. Notice that $\binom{n}{k}:=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Then if $C(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kz^k$ and $D(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k z^k$, your sum will be the $z^n$ coefficient of $C(z)D(z)$. It's easy to see that $D(z)=(1+bz)^n$ and a little harder that $C(z)=L_r(az)$ where $L_r(z)$ is the [polylogorithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html). Thus, to find your sum, you need to differentiate $(1+bz)^nL_r(az)$ exactly $n$ times and divide by $n!$.